# How do I add CollectionViewController into ViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Based on the SimpleCollectionView sample, I have successfully add CollectionViewController into ViewController but I get an error when I  clicked on the items in the CollectionViewController. Below are the codes for references.

```
UICollectionViewController simpleCollectionViewController;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    simpleCollectionViewController = new SimpleCollectionViewController(new LineLayout());
    View.AddSubView(simpleCollectionViewController.View);
}
```

Really hope someone willing to guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your controller has been released
just try this

```
//self is the base controller
[self addChildViewController: simpleCollectionViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks Gpake...it works after I add this code before the AddSubView. Btw, may I know what do you mean on the "controller has been released". Where I can get more info on this?

Comment: @user2684768   i don't know mono can use ARC. but if yes, that controller had not been added as childView controller, the ARC will reduce its reference(retain) count. if added, retain count will be added by one; this keeps the controller alive. If you can not understand what i'm talking,just read [Apple's About Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)